# Wielandt automorphism tower theorem

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I wanted to know if anyone can point me to an (ideally freely available) english translation of the proof of Wielandt's Automorphism Tower Theorem (1939).

The theorem states the following:
Given a finite, centerless group $G$, its automorphism tower terminates (stabilizes) in finitely many steps.

Answer (score 4):

Proofs of this theorem are available in textbooks. See e.g. a list in Proc. AMS 89(1983), pp 182-183 [note](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-089-01/S0002-9939-1983-0706537-X/S0002-9939-1983-0706537-X.pdf) by Martin Pettet.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the textbooks referenced discuss bounds on how many steps it takes to stabilize (which is also the topic of the note), but I don't know if they actually cover the proof of Wielandt's theorem (it's probable that they do however).

Comment: Robinson's book does give a complete proof in Sect. 13.5, and not too long either. And no, it does not discuss explicit bounds, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It appears to be possible to download a pdf of Robinson's book from 
https://ia600204.us.archive.org/16/items/springer_10.1007-978-1-4419-8594-1/10.1007-978-1-4419-8594-1.pdf

(I got this link at https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4419-8594-1)

Answer (score 4):

The theorem appears as Theorem 9.10 in

*Isaacs, I.Martin*, Finite group theory. Graduate Studies in Mathematics 92. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (ISBN 978-0-8218-4344-4/hbk). xi, 350~p. (2008). [DOI 10.1090/gsm/092](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/gsm/092). [ZBL1169.20001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1169.20001), [MR2426855](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2426855).

The proof given there is very detailed (and well written). (But I think this book is not freely available.)